# C++ What exactly happened here?

Tags: c++, gcc

While doing a program, I came up with an unintended behaviour in dynamic arrays. After I did a few tests, I ended up with this code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

unsigned long index;

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void Set()
    {
        T* target = new T[index];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            target[i] = i;
        }
        this->value_ = target;
        index++;
    }

    T* value_;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> test;
    test.Set();
    std::cout << test.value_[0] << '\n';
    test.Set();
    std::cout << test.value_[1];
}
```

Returning the following values:

```
11104472
11075776
```

The values change each time I execute the program, however, I thought the output would be "0" and "1". I suppose they are memory addresses, but why is the program returning them and not the expected output?

Comment: Ask yourself: When I do `T* target = new T[index];`, what is the value of `index`?  How big of an array do I now have?

Comment: @NathanOliver That would be appliable during the first ```test.Set()```, but in the second one, ```index``` would be 1 so output shouldn't be a random memory address too

Comment: You might think that, but once you've entered undefined behavior land, there's no going back.  It's like Hotel California that way ;)

Comment: @Salty27: Same thing for the second. Now you're allocating an array of size one, and accessing the second element. Oops.

Comment: @NathanOliver initializing ```index``` to 1 fixed the problem

Comment: With `index` auto-initialized to zero: You are both times accessing one element beyond the end of the array. At the first `Set`, you create an array of zero elements but then you access the first element (`[0]`). Next time, you create an array of one element but then you access the second element (`[1]`). (Plus, you never `delete[]` the things you created, leaking memory every time `Set` is called.)

Comment: @Salty27: Or moving the increment of `index` to the top of `Set()`.

Comment: Any time you get in this situation you should use a debugger to step through your code 1 line at a time looking at your variables at each step. If you did this carefully you would have seen that you allocated an array of size 0 on the first time you called Set. You would have also seen that the `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; i++)` loop was not entered the first time.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xWc1f4MoG vs https://godbolt.org/z/bThfcKdvz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look which values `index` will have. It is initialized with 0. So in the first `test.Set();` you create an 0 length array. To even read it later is wrong and leads to so called undefined behavior. In the second call of set, index will have a value of 1, so you create an array of length 1 and initialize that first element on position 0 correctly with 0, but you then try to print out `test.value_[1]` which is not the first element but the second. Remember array indices start with 0. So this is also an out of bounds read i.e. a wrong doing punishable by random behavior.